# underscore bind: returning functions

Tags: javascript

```
onPlayerStateChange: function() {
  return _.bind(function (event) {
    var player = event.target;
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      this.trigger("playing");
  }, this);
},
```

The above code is my final version and it works great. However, I am not 100% certain why

```
onPlayerStateChange: _.bind(function (event) { // <-- Missing 'function', 'return' keywords
    var player = event.target;
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      this.trigger("playing");
  }, this);
},
```

this doesn't work. It seems `_.bind` function itself runs when `onPlayerStateChange` is called. However, what I want is the function returned by `_.bind` function to run. Could someone elaborate the subtle difference between these two versions?

Answer (score 0):

You missplaced your closing bracket. This should work:

```
onPlayerStateChange: _.bind(function (event) { 
    var player = event.target;
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      this.trigger("playing");
    }
}, this)
```